# What does com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService do: Round Two?

Tags: ios-simulator

I've been trying to find out what this does.
I see an old question that asked the same thing from 5 years ago: but nobody was able to answer it, or a least nobody that saw it was:
[What does com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564160/what-does-com-apple-coresimulator-coresimulatorservice-do)

I came across it when I was trying to do a Disk Utility Verify & Repair on High Sierra on my internal Data Drive (not my System drive, that's a separate Disk).

And after various attempts, I got a message saying that this service was preventing it.
So I killed it, and was then able to do what I wanted without any obvious adverse affects.
No Magic Smoke, no Blue Screen of Death etc etc.

Do I actually NEED to have this service running?
Activity Monitor says it's consuming a lot of resources (I did not write it down, but will look next time I reboot if it's gone up again).

If there's a good place to read up on Apple things like this that would be even better: I'd rather learn to fish than have someone hand me a can of opened sardines...:-}

Answer (score 1):

It appears to manage simulators for different apple devices with xcode. For example, when you run a watch os simulator to test an app.

If you run this command, you can see the list of simulators. If you get errors on these, you might need to clean out the list and it will be recreated when xcode starts up again.

```
xcrun simctl list
```

You can shutdown simulators with

```
xcrun simctl shutdown all
```

Comment: Does it make sense that CoreSimulator would be running (not idle) in a non-programming environment? (Ie. Xcode is not being used on the system since restart)